# Is "... his mother was possessed of a tyrannical nature and led her peasants and also her immediate family a miserable life." correct?

Tags: grammaticality

*His early youth was spent on a country estate where he was able to observe the life of the
serfs and the relations between master and serf at their worst: his mother was possessed of a tyrannical nature and led her
peasants and also her immediate family a miserable life.*

The sentence comes from Nabokov's *Lectures on Russian Literature*. Is the sentence correct? Can you lead somebody a miserable life? Or is ***lead*** used in the sentence as a [verb](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lead#Verb) that is pronounced /lɛd/?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> … his mother was possessed of a tyrannical nature and *led* her peasants and also her immediate family a miserable life.

In idiomatic Present Day English, *lead* (past *led*) is not a [*ditransitive verb*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ditransitive_verb#In_English), i.e., one which takes two objects, like *elected her president* or *gave me a lecture.*

Curiously enough, this has not always been the case:

> … if he behave himself well; but, if otherwise, they *[lead him a Life](https://books.google.de/books?id=ssNCAQAAMAAJ&pg=RA2-PA33&dq=%22lead%20him%20a%20life%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiDwJ_AuKDkAhWF26QKHZ2hBiUQ6AEIJzAA)* (as they say) like a Dog.— Roger North, *The Life of the Honourable Sir Dudley North*, 1744.

But Nabokov’s lectures were published in 1981.

What is missing is a causative — the tyrannical mother *caused* them to lead a miserable life – or a resultative — the mother *made* their lives *miserable*.

The easiest way to edit the clause would be to add a dependent infinitive:

> … his mother was possessed of a tyrannical nature and led her peasants and also her immediate family *to suffer* a miserable life.

I wonder whether something like this was somehow omitted.

I could not readily find any details about Nabokov’s role in the publication of this book beyond his having given the lectures himself at various American universities. A [*New York Times* review](https://www.nytimes.com/1981/10/25/books/nabokov-s-russians.html) at the time of publication notes:

> Fredson Bowers, who edited both volumes, says Nabokov's lectures were mainly handwritten. Sometimes they lacked clear organization, and parts remained in rough notes.

Whatever the case, a proofreader at the publishing house certainly should have caught the error.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is correct English. In this context **lead** is a verb (pronounced /lɛd/), the past tense of the verb **to lead**. As you may work out from the context, it means

> "... his mother made the lives of her peasants and also her immediate family miserable [because of her tyrannical nature]"